# How to apply a function over several matrices in R

Tags: r, function, matrix

I would like to apply a function over several matrices and the output should be list or vector reporting the result of each operation.
so my attemp was with mapply and looked like this:

```
    myfunction<-function(x){cor(df1,x)
    output.list<-mapply(myfunction(df2,df3))
```

but this didn't work out. Any ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `lapply(list(df2, df3), myfunction)`.